# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. What is the best solution?

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

when i try to run an app written by others in a different PC in my android studio, i get this error message.

Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings
Use Embedded JDK (C:\Program Files\Android\Android2\jre)
Change JDK location.

I just want to run this in my AStudio and check the app. what is best and easiest recommendation..

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File > Project Structure** and change JDK location to Embedded JDK You can use short key **Ctr+Alt+Shift+S**

[image: Here is image]